# Qual dbsource em R devo utilizar para arquivos de dados extraídos do ScienceDirect?

Tags: r

Quando extraio arquivos da Base Scopus utilizo:

```
Scop_Bibl <- convert2df("scopus_LOG-SMC-SD.bib", dbsource = "scopus", format = "bibtex")
```

Já quando extraio arquivos da base WebofScience uso:

```
WOS_Bib <- convert2df("WOS_LOG-SCM-SD.bib", dbsource = "wos", format = "bibtex")
```

Qual seria o `dbsource` adequado para a base ScienceDirect em R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(bibliometrix)
```

Tem um tutorial muito bom da Bea Milz [neste post](https://beamilz.com/posts/2021-03-07-estudando-bibliometrix/pt/). Inclusive a sugestão que apresento aqui é baseado nesse tutorial dela.

O que acontece é que são vários arquivos baixados pelo woS.
Sendo assim, você vai precisar primeiro, listar os arquivos que precisa abrir. Eles começam pelo padrão "savedrec_". Então vc pode colocar a regex `"savedrecs_"` no argumento `pattern =`

```
arquivos_wos <- list.files(path = "DIRETORIO ONDE ESTAO OS ARQUVOS BAIXADOS DO WoS",
                           pattern = "^savedrecs_", 
                           full.names = TRUE)
```

E aplica a função `convert2df()` para importá-los, utilizando o vetor para indicar o caminho dos arquivos (argumento `file =`)

```
dados_wos <- bibliometrix::convert2df(file = arquivos_wos,
                                      dbsource = "wos",
                                      format = "bibtex")
```